# Using ZeroMQ in a crossplatform desktop/mobile app-suite for architecture concerns

Tags: c++, networking, architecture, zeromq, decoupling

I need to make an architecture decision on a cross-platform app-suite. I basically want to try new way of decoupling modules and implement network I/O  using ZeroMQ, knowing it's a message queue for in-process, inter-process and networking applications. But I'm not sure how it can fit in with my case.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could clarify a few things before I spend the next week reading their intriguing book: http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all

I've checked these questions but didn't get my answers:

- [How to use zeroMQ in Desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124546/how-to-use-zeromq-in-desktop-application)
- [How to use ZeroMQ in an GTK/QT/Clutter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452131/how-to-use-zeromq-in-an-gtk-qt-clutter-application)

**My requirements:**

- Desktop hosts on Windows and macOS, as separated console backend and GUI frontend; the backend must be written in C++;
- Mobile guests on iOS and Android, backend written in C++;
- Desktop talks with mobile using TCP;

**Old Way**

As for the desktop backend (the console app), a few years back, my first step would be writing a multithreaded architecture based on Observer/Command patterns:

- Set the main thread for UI and spawn a few threads.
- One "scheduler" thread for message handling: a queue to get notifications from other modules and another queue for commands. Each command type introduces its own dependencies. The scheduler pumps messages and issues commands accordingly.
- Other "executor" threads for device monitoring, multiplex network I/O between **one desktop and multiple mobile devices**, all sending messages to scheduler to have real work scheduled.

I would then need to implement thread-safe message queues, and will inevitably have coupling between schedulers and a bunch of Command classes that are essentially just function wrappers of those executors' behaviors. With C++, this would be a lot of boilerplate code.

**New Way to Validate**

But it's 2019 so I expect less hand-written code and would try something new. With ZeroMQ, I'd love to see if my expectation holds. I'd love to ...

- Remove the need of writing a scheduler and message/command queues from scrach, by just passing ZeroMQ requests between in-process modules across threads, because writing scheduling from scratch is tedious and unproductive.
- Simplify network I/O between desktop and mobile devices. For this part I've tried ASIO and it wasn't significantly more convenient than raw socket and select, plus it's C++-only.
- Decouple GUI and console app with ZeroMQ-based IPC, so that GUI can be rewritten using different technologies in various languages.
- Perceive low-latency for both desktop and mobile users.

Is my expectation reasonable?

Comment: You can do this with ZMQ for certain but Websocket could also be a solution (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682634/differences-between-zeromq-and-websockets) ).

Comment: @Clonk Thanks! The link helps. Not sure how browser would play a part in my usecase though if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>If new to ZeroMQ domains, feel free to review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) and best enjoy a very first look at ["ZeroMQ **Principles** in less than **Five Seconds**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571) before diving into further details</sub>

---

An above referred post has presented an assumption, that:

> *ZeroMQ is based on the assumption that there is an `while (1) ...` loop that it is inserted into*

is completely wrong and misleading any Architecture planning / assessment efforts.

ZeroMQ is a feature-rich signaling/messaging metaplane, that is intended to provide a lot of services for the application-level code, that may enjoy a light-weight re-use of the smart, complex on low-level, efficient handling of signaling/messaging infrastructure, be it used for in-process, inter-process and inter-node multi-agent distributed fashion, using for that goal many already available transport-class protocols:

**`{ inproc:// | ipc:// | tipc:// | vmci:// | tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | udp:// }`**

---

### This said, let's follow your shopping-list :

> ***My requirements:***

- **`c++` ZeroMQ: [PASSED]** Desktop hosts on Windows and macOS, as separated console backend and GUI frontend; the backend must be written in C++;
- **`c++` ZeroMQ: [PASSED]** Mobile guests on iOS and Android, backend written in C++;
- **`tcp` ZeroMQ: [PASSED]** Desktop talks with mobile using TCP;

---

> ***I'd love to ...***
>
> - Remove the need of writing a **scheduler** and message/command **queues** from scrach, by just passing ZeroMQ requests between in-process modules across threads, because writing scheduling from scratch is tedious and unproductive.
> - **Simplify network I/O** between desktop and mobile devices. For this part I've tried ASIO and it wasn't significantly more convenient than raw socket and select, plus it's C++-only.
> - **Decouple** GUI and console app with ZeroMQ-based IPC, so that GUI can be rewritten using different technologies in various languages.
> - Perceive **low-latency** for both desktop and mobile users.
>
> ***Is my expectation reasonable?***

Well :

- there is obviously no need to write **scheduler+Queues** from scratch. Queue-management is built-in ZeroMQ and actually hidden inside the service-metaplane. Scheduling things among many-actors is on the other hand your design-decision and has nothing to do with ZeroMQ or other technology of choice. Given your system-design intentions, you decide the way ( "autogenerated magics" are still more a wishful thinking than any near-future system design reality )

**[PASSED] QUEUES** : built-in ZeroMQ
**[NICE2HAVE] SCHEDULER** : auto-generated for any generic distributed many-agent-wide ecosystem <sub>(yet, hard to expect in any near future)</sub>

- network ( and any in principle ) I/O is simplified already in the ZeroMQ hierarchy of services

**[PASSED]** : **SIMPLIFIED NETWORK I/O** - ZeroMQ provides already all abstracted Transport-Class related services hidden to the transparent use of the signaling/messaging metaplane,
so the **application** code enjoys to **"*just*" `{ .send() | .poll() | .recv() }`**

**[PASSED]** : **Decoupling** GUI from any other part of the ParcPlace-Systems-pioneered-MVC-architecture. Using this since ZeroMQ v2.11 for a (far)remote keyboard over TCP/IP network and even possible to integrate into actor-based GUI, like Tkinter-GUI actors may well serve this distributed local-**V**isual/remote-distributed-**C**ontroller/remote-distributed-**M**odel. If mobile-terminal O/S introduces more complex constraints on the local-**V**isual MVC-component, proper adaptations ought be validated with domain-experts on that particular O/S properties. ZeroMQ signaling/messaging metaplane has not been considered so far to contain any constraints per se.

**[PASSED]** : **LATENCY** - ZeroMQ was designed from the very start for delivering ultimately low-latency as a must. Given it can feed HFT-tranding ecosystems, the Desktop/Mobile systems are orders of magnitude less restrictive in the sense of E2E lump sum accumulation of all the visited transport + O/S-handling latencies.